# How to convert vector iterator to int in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am looking for an element in a C++ vector, and when I find it, I want to get found element's index in a numerical form(integer, float).

My naive attempt is this :

```
int x;
int index;
vector<int> myvector;
vector<int>::iterator it;
it = find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), x);  
index = (int) * it;
```

This code is giving error. Can you tell me how I can convert iterator to int(if possible), or can you tell me how I can get found element's index in other way? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error? The cast is pointless (but not incorrect), since `*it` is already the value you want, and you should check it's not equal to `myvector.end()` before dereferencing (otherwise you'll get a runtime error or other undefined behaviour).

Comment: Just a note. You don't want to convert iterator to an `int` it very rarely makes any sense. Iterator is more like a pointer in c++ standard library nomenclature, so it points to a place and you can dereference it. And when you get it you can measure a distance since the beginning, just like with pointers (more or less).

Comment: Sorry, I missed what you actually want (the element's index, not the value). See my answer.

Comment: You need to make sure `it != myvector.end()` before you try to dereference it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to use standard function `std::distance`

```
index = std::distance( myvector.begin(), it );

if ( index < myvector.size() )
{
    // do something with the vector element with that index
}
```

Try always to use `std::distance` even with random access iterators. This function is available in the new and old C++ Standards.

Answer (score 17):

If you want the index of the found element, then that's the distance from the start of the sequence:

```
index = it - myvector.begin();
```

or, since C++11,

```
index = std::distance(myvector.begin(), it);
```

which will work with any forward iterator type, not just random-access ones like those from a vector.