# How does the subtraction of two iterators denote the index of a vector item in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In a blogpost of GeeksForGeeks, subtraction of two iterators has been used to denote the index of a vector. Link of that post:

[std::find in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/std-find-in-cpp/)

I have also seen a related answer in stackoverflow:

[How to convert vector iterator to int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995725/how-to-convert-vector-iterator-to-int-in-c)

But it didn't describe the mechanism with a good example, so I am confused about this. Because, I can't print the iterators **v.begin()** and **it** separately while I can print the subtraction value of them which is **( it - v.begin() )**.

So, how does that subtraction denotes the index of a vector item?

Comment: vectors have random access iterators so see the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) which gives the semantics of subtracting 2 iterators

Comment: Are you actually asking _why_ `i - j` gives a number? Or why that number can be used as an index? Or _how_ `std::distance` is implemented?

Comment: @Useless Actually I am asking about both why i-j gives a number (as I cannot print i and j separately) and how that number can be used as an idex?

Comment: What is `begin()-begin()`, and what is the index of the first element? What is `(begin()+1) - begin()`, and what is the index of the second element? And so on - just spend some time thinking through examples until you understand.

Comment: The precise but unsatisfying answer is that it's because that's what the standard requires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtracting one [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) from another gives the distance between them, because that's what `operator-` is defined to do for random access iterators.

If you subtract `begin()` from another iterator, you get the distance from the beginning of the container to the second iterator, which is naturally the same value as the index of the element referenced by the second iterator.

Using [`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) instead of the operator overload is more flexible, and possibly clearer.

All this stuff is documented and should be covered in a decent book.

Comment: Why can't I print **v.begin()** or **it** separately while I can print the substraction value of them which is **( it - v.begin() )** ?

Comment: What type is the object returned by [`v.begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)? Is there an `operator<<` defined for it? What would you expect to see printed for an iterator? What happens if you define an appropriate stream insertion operator yourself? What happens if you try to print `*v.begin()` instead?

Comment: These are all things you can think through carefully on your own. If you try to print an iterator, you get an error message which contains information and which you should read and try to understand.